# Upper bound for $\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: functions, factorial, radicals

It is straight forward to show that $\sqrt[n]{n!} < n$ from:

- $2 > \sqrt{2}$
- $\frac{n+1}{n} > \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$ since $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}} > \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$

Is this the best that can be done?  Is it possible to find a better upper bound for $\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

by using $AM-GM$ we have $$\frac{1+2+3+...+n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{n!}$$
using the well-known formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers we get
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2n}\geq \sqrt[n]{n!}$$ thus we get
$$\sqrt[n]{n!}\le \frac{n+1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

We find an inequality using Stirling's approximation at [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html):

$$n!<\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n+1/(12n)}$$

Which means

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}<\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n+1/(12n)}}$$

Which is

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}<\frac{n}{e}\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot e^{1/(12n)}}$$

This is not as pretty as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's inequality; it is however a lot better at approximating $\sqrt[n]{n!}$.