# which of the following, inequalities is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, factorial, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

let n ≥ 3 be an integer . then the statement

$ ({n!}) ^{\frac{1} {n} } $ ≤  $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is

A) true for every n ≥ 3

B)true if and only if n ≥ 5

C) not true for n ≥ 10

D) true for even integers n≥ 6,not true for odd n ≥ 5

my attempts ;  i was using the stirling formula  $ n! = e^{-n} {n^{n}}  $,,
now im getting  $ ({n!}) ^{\frac{1} {n} } $ $  = (e^{-n} {n^{n}})^\frac{1}{n}  $ = $ \frac{n}{e} $ ≤  $\frac{n+1}{2}$..which is true for every n ≥ 3....so correct option is option A).

Is my answer is correct or not .pliz verified  and tell me the solution i would be more thankful..

Comment: Where did you get the equation $n!=e^{-n}n^n$? That is wrong. Consider $$n!=e^{-n}n^n\Leftrightarrow \frac{n^n}{n!}=e^n.$$ The LHS is a rational number while the RHS is a transendent number. So your argument is not valid.

Comment: Nevertheless A) is the right answer. You should try to prove it by induction.

Comment: @ Mundron Schmidt   ihave taken this equation $ n! = e^{-n} {n^{n}}  $  from Serge Lang undergrauduate  analysis book

Comment: Then there is a huge error in the book. You can also directly see for the case $n=1$ the equation claims $1!=e^{-1}1^1$ which yields $e=1$. Like I explained, the equation is wrong for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Nevertheless, you can prove the statement A) using induction :-)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202254/upper-bound-for-sqrtnn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're confusing an asymptotic estimate with an equivalence, since the formula you wrote is (obviously) not true: you can simply try it for low values for $n$.

So, the inequality is true for $n=3$, since $6^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq 4$ (you can try to add some details to understand this inequality without any calculation). This fact shows that the B) case is false.

Moreover, if you work by induction, you can see that the option A) is the correct one. In fact:

$$
{\left((n+1)n!\right)}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\leq {(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{n+1}{2}\leq \frac{n+2}{2}
$$

You can provide details for yourself.

Comment: thanks a lots @ Dario

Comment: Are you lomber, Dario?  I know lomber has been suspended for having multiple accounts and cross upvoting them, so if an account of the same user who owns lomber's account, I'd close the account asap.

Comment: Hi @amWhy, i don't know who lomber is, my account is actually unique, why do you think differently? And how could I prove that I'm not using multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM $$\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{1+2+...+n}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{n!}$$

Comment: that was really beautiful @ michael Rozenberg,,,thanks a lot

Comment: @lomber lego You are welcome! Good luck!