# Proof by induction involving an inequality and $n!$

Tags: induction, formal-proofs

## Proposition:

$$
P_n \ : \sqrt[n]{n!} \le \frac{n+1}{2} , \hspace{0.5em}\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$

## Proof:

$$
P_1 : \text{Let} \ n=1 , \hspace{1em}\sqrt{1!} \le \frac{1+1}{2} \implies 1 = 1 , \ \therefore P_1 \text{is true}
$$

$$
P_k : \text{Suppose} \ \exists k \ \text{s.t.}  \hspace{1em}\sqrt[k]{k!} \le \frac{k+1}{2} , \hspace{0.5em}\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$

$$
P_{k+1} : \text{Consider now ,} \hspace{1em} \sqrt[k+1]{(k+1)!} \le \frac{k+2}{2}
$$

$$
\implies \sqrt[k+1]{(k+1) \cdot k \cdot (k-1)... 2\cdot1} \le \frac{k+2}{2}
$$

## Question:

I am unsure how to bring $P_k$ into this expression and proceed further.
What should I consider to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have to use induction? Because it easily follows from the AM/GM inequality: $$\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdots a_n}\leq \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2202255/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Bn!%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7B2%7D%24)